# Find angularjs version

Tags: angularjs

I tried in browser console:

```
angular.version
```

And I got below

> codeName : "foam-acceleration" dot : 3 full : "1.4.3" major : 1 minor
>   : 4

So what angular version is used? Is it angular2 or 4 or any other?

Thanks

Comment: It's `angular 1.4.3`.. mentioned in string  "1.4.3"

Answer (score 1):

You can console '**angular.version.full**' for getting version of angular being used on that webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Neither. It is not angular 2 or 4. It is AngularJS 1.4.3, which is what we commonly refer to as AngularJS 1.x

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can we call angular 1.x as Angular 1? And, Is it like Angular 1.x is outdated and we should use angular2 or 4?

Comment: Angular 1.x is called AngularJS.
Angular 2.x and Angular 4.x are called Angular (or Angular 2/4)

Comment: You can refer to it as just `AngularJS`. Version 2 and above are called `Angular` (without the JS)

Comment: AngularJS 1.x is an older version. But, I wouldn't call it outdated, yet. There is still a very active community of developers using it. Angular 2 and above are not backwards compatible with AngularJS. Hence, a lot of projects who started with AngularJS 1.x are still stuck at version 1.x.

Comment: @CodeWarrior AngularJS (1.x) is definitely outdated now.

Answer (score 0):

Your current Angular version is **1.4.3**.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/object/angular.version

`full` is the current fullname version.

`major`, `minor` and `dot` are the 1.4.3 (*major*.*minor*.*dot*)